# как удалить повторяющиеся значения в массиве чтобы остались только не повторяющиеся

Tags: php

Есть массив

```
Array
(
 [0] => 1
 [1] => 2
 [2] => 2
)
```

как удалить из него повторяющиеся значения? Чтобы результат был

```
Array
(
 [0] => 1
)
```

array_unique оставляет одну двойку, которая не нужна

Comment: Смотрите дубликат. там много способов

Comment: Это не дубликат т.к. результат другой

Comment: это почему же? вы проверяли? особенно короткий ответ от VenZell

Comment: да Ваш - решение без цикла лучшего ответа

Comment: И по выводам видно что не подходит

Comment: в чем именно не подходит? код убирает именно дублирубщиеся значения и оставляет те, которые представлены в массиве в единственном значении..... что **именно** не подходит? и почему?

Comment: Ваше решение без цикла мне не помогло я не знаю почему. в конце остается 2, которое мне не нужно. А код Arnial помог

Comment: решение от VenZell : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5db392dafa61e998ece88911482338a6e02993ef   работоспособно.

Comment: Спасибо, Алексей!

Comment: Пойду удалю последнее решение) что-то там правда баг при разных данных

Comment: Кстати ответ от @Arnial похож на ответ ReinRaus в том самом дубликате., хотя конечно в теории он зря его тут удалил так или иначе)